# Get ID of first LI of UL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
<ul id="someList">
<li id="listItem1">List 1</li>
<li id="listItem2">List 2</li>
</ul>
```

Maybe I need to brush up on my selectors, but how would you grab the first ID of ul#someList?

Also if I'm prepending LI's to ul#someList, will I need to grab the first LI's ID in a different way?

Comment: If the purpose is to prepend, then all you need is the `#someList` element to call `.prepend()` on. `$('#someList').prepend('<li>some new item</li>');`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$('ul#someList li:first')` is what you're looking for.

Comment: To get the element that is; `$('ul#someList li:first').attr('id')` to get the ID itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use the [first selector.](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
var id = $("ul#someList li:first").attr("id");
```

or

```
var id = $("ul#someList li:first").get(0).id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try, ****.slice( start, [ end ] )****`

```
<ul>
  <li id='l1'>list item 1</li>
  <li id='l2'>list item 2</li>
  <li id='l3'>list item 3</li>
  <li id='l4'>list item 4</li>
  <li id='l5'>list item 5</li>
</ul>

$('li').slice(2).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be another solution:

```
$('#someList li:nth-child(1)').attr("id");
```