# How to jump to the anchor of the first li?

Tags: jquery

Here is the html code :

```
<span class="expander"><span class="caret"></span></span>
<ul class="expander-target displaynone">
     <li><a href="http://localhost:8008/management/ecshop/edit">aaaaaaaa</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost:8008/management/coupon">bbbbbbb</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost:8008/management/sale">ccccccc</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost:8008/management/mail/template">ddddddd</a></li>
</ul>
```

Below is the jquery code:

```
   $('.expander').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(this).nextAll('.expander-target').slideToggle('fast');
                   //console.log($(this).siblings("ul li:first-child").attr("href");  
  });
```

how to write the code to jump to the first li anchor address? thanks

Comment: check this  the answer contain, what you want


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323186/get-id-of-first-li-of-ul-with-jquery

Comment: there is a <a> in it, it is different

Answer (score 1):

just use this

```
console.log($(".expander-target li:first  a").attr("href"));
```

here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kos11eo3/)

**update**

To get it using `this` use this, it will find next `ul` from clicked item

```
console.log($(this).next("ul.expander-target").find('li:first a').attr("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert($(".expander-target li:first-child a").attr("href"));
    alert($("ul li:first-child a").attr("href"));
 });
```

[API details here](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)